# Windows 7 doesn't start after installing a game with StarForce protection

Tags: windows-7, copy-protection, system-recovery

I installed a game, which uses the StarForce protection under Windows 7 (64-bit).

After game installation, StarForce displayed a message, asking for a reboot. Since the reboot, Windows 7 doesn't start properly. It shows a text mode dialog (*Recovery* or *Start Windows normally*). Selecting any option leads to graphic mode rescue dialog (that with many different options). Sadly, I have to system images.

**Is there a way to recover Windows 7 by deleting some files?**
(By using GParted or something...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [StarForce – the ultimate evil](http://swiftcoder.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/starforce-the-ultimate-evil/) :

> No big deal, boot up in safe mode and
> delete the problematic drivers, right?
> No such luck, StarForce had even
> managed to install these broken
> drivers in safe mode.
>
> Next stop, the Vista installation
> disk, which has a repair feature. The
> repair went as expected, showed
> success, but when I tried to reboot,
> the problem was still there.
>
> Luckily I had a Knoppix Live-CD lying
> around from some old experiments, and
> this was able to boot the machine into
> linux. A couple of driver downloads
> later I was able to access the files
> on the main hard drive, and delete the
> offending StarForce drivers by hand,
> which fixed the problem.

List of drivers from [How can I get rid of Starforce?](http://www.glop.org/starforce/remove.php) :

> Unofficial way to remove Starforce
>
> 1. Remove these files:
>    %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\sfsync03.sys
>    %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\sfhlp02.sys
>    %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\sfdrv01.sys
> 2. Remove these registry keys:
>    HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\sfsync03
>    HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\sfhlp02
>    HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\sfdrv01

Comment: Removed the files. One or two files had higher numbers at the end. Now, I'm going to restart and see...

Comment: StarForce offers (nowadays) removal program: http://www.star-force.com/support/drivers/ . I tried them and it worked. (used on Win10)

Comment: Thanks, Got the same error on win 10 but deleting these files saved me and my pc

Answer (score 1):

God bless Star-Force - punishing people who buy games whilst pirates who download the game apply a patch and never even know that Star-Force is the DRM.

At the start of your system, even before the screen comes up that asks to go in to recovery, try pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> and choose `Safe Mode`. Once in, follow the guide [from Star-Force's website](http://www.star-force.com/support/drivers/) and you can try an update, but if it still fails to start, do a full removal uninstall of the game and driver.

Comment: Sadly, `safe mode` also brings me to that graphic recovery screen :(

Comment: What about booting to Last Known Good Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When this problem occurs, you can press F8 to enter the boot menu. Safe mode etc. Choose `disable driver signature enforcement` to enter windows normally and fix this problem.
Unfortunately, you cannot fix this problem by just doing system restore